# Interpretations of infinitesimal displacements and virtual displacements in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, infinitesimals, tangent-bundle

I have started a book on theoretical mechanics which in the beginning is stated that in order to understand properly the material one should know manifold theory and differential geometry very well and there are other recommended books and also short appendix on this topic. It all was good until few pages further the motions of infinitesimal distance and displacements and virtual displacements started to occur. There was no single line about them in the appendix and also cannot find exact definition of these term in the given books. So my question is how these notions are well mathematically defined in terms of differential geometric structures (maps from where to where and why and how) and where I can find further information about them?
EDIT: If there is way not to use infinitesimals but standard notions, it would be better.

Comment: It might be helpful if you name the book.

Comment: It is old book not in English but I know from trusted people that the book is all right and correct the only thing is that I cannot get where infinitesimals comes from.

Comment: You are misunderstanding my question.  I don't suspect the book is *wrong*, I think it would be easier to help you if we could see what the book actually says.  Is there some reason that you don't want to mention its title and author?

Comment: It is in Bulgarian and it is old book. In that time there were not any special ways of printing formulas so instead of writing then the author deactibed them.

Comment: Key words to look up: Tangent vector, tangent bundle, vector field.

Comment: I know what tangent vector, bundle and vector field is. In the appendix they are explained in set-theoretical manner and it is clear for me how they work but nothing is said about the terms above.

Comment: I would be so thankful if you could help me somehow in order to reach some good answers. I have been looking for explanations on the internet but most of them describe them using nonstandard calculus or just saying that they are small changes which is not very serious.

Comment: I will repeat my question:  Is there some reason you don't want to mention the title and author of the book?

Comment: Yes, because it is a book made out of other books and lecture notes and it has not got any particular author but it is group and this book has never been published or printed or anything like this.

Comment: Please, somehow help if you know something or vote in order to become more popular question. Please!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are primarily interested in is mathematical physics then it may make sense to work with actual infinitesimal displacements that can be developed as a rigorous basis for differential geometry, as in [this publication](http://www.logicandanalysis.com/index.php/jla/article/view/237). A more detailed version of this approach can be found in [this set of lecture notes](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/tidg.pdf) currently being used in a course on true infinitesimal differential geometry.